# Not able to bind a model to an input using Vue.js and Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm getting used to Vue.js but seem to stumble on the basics here...
I use Laravel 5.4 which has Vue.js included, so I got this code in my view:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="POST" action="{{ route('login') }}" id="loginform">
<div class="field columns">
    <p class="control column is-half">
        <a class="button is-success is-fullwidth">Login</a>
    </p>
    <p class="control column is-half">
        <input type="text" v-model="rememberme" name="remember">
        <a class="button is-light is-fullwidth"><span class="fa fa-square-o fa-vertical-middle fa-has-margin fa-force-1rem"></span>Remember me</a>
    </p>
</div>
```

```
<script>
    new Vue({
        el:'#loginform',
        data: {
            rememberme: 1
        }
    });
</script>
```

But no matter what I do, I always get

> app.js:19558 [Vue warn]: Property or method "rememberme" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure to declare reactive data properties in the data option.

So I was checking google and reviewed some online tutorials, but I still got that problem.
In my layout I've loaded the app.js before the script-section, so Vue.js is actually there.

Comment: Your code should work. https://jsfiddle.net/fL4bdzd5/ What do you mean "I've loaded the app.js before the script-section"?

Comment: Heyho, well I'm on the state "it should work - why the heck isn't it working!?" ;)
I mean that my layouts-file loads the compiled app.js (which include vue) before the scripttag.

Comment: Well, there must be something you're not including in your post. How is your code different from the fiddle I shared?

Comment: I've uploaded the full HTML here: https://pastebin.com/EDqpKZrZ

Comment: I'm assuming your `http://moya.local/js/app.js` file contains a Vue instance bound to the #app div?

Comment: i've checked and yes it does.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146803/discussion-between-thanksd-and-husky110).

Answer (score 1):

From the [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/EDqpKZrZ) you shared, you can see that you already have a script `app.js` which contains a Vue instance with the root `#app` div as the element bound to the instance.

Because of this, that first Vue instance is seeing the `rememberme` property within the `#app` div, but doesn't have a `rememberme` property itself, so it's giving you that warning.

Just add the `rememberme` property to the Vue instance in the `app.js` script:

```
const app = new Vue({
   el: '#app',
   data: {
     rememberme: 1
   }
});
```